# Protected left turn traffic signal data

Tags: geospatial, traffic

I wonder if there is a dataset of protected left turn (a left-oriented arrow) traffic signal? For example, a GIS dataset of the location of traffic lights that have this signal.

I thought this information should be essential and easy to be found. However, after I've looked up many detailed traffic signal datasets (data.gov, OpenStreetMaps, and [GIS open data websites](http://gisdata-arlgis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/af497e2747104622ac74f4457b3fb73f_2)), none of them seems to have protected left turn signal information.

If there is no such dataset, what would be the rationale of lacking such data? US data preferred.

Comment: @Jan Doggen I would say for the US temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSM has this data, [you can search for tags here](https://tagfinder.herokuapp.com/search?query=turn%3Alanes%3Dleft&lang=en).
You can read more here: [Mapping Turning Lanes in OpenStreetMap](https://blog.mapbox.com/mapping-turn-lanes-in-openstreetmap-5da9bf764f0d), and view [key `turn`'s documentation here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:turn#Turning_indications_per_lane).
[OpenStreetMap's Forum](https://help.openstreetmap.org/) is essentially Stack Exchange for OSM, as well as [OSM Slack](https://awesomestreetmap.slack.com/)